# Using generated graphql query types with my custom React hook inside Gatsby and Typescript project

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby, graphql-codegen

I created a custom React hook in my Gatsby (and Typescript) project for my Site Metadata:

```
// hooks/useSiteMetadata.ts
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

const useSiteMetadata = () => {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query SiteMetaData {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            year
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  );
  return site.siteMetadata;
};

export default useSiteMetadata;
```

Inside e.g. `Header.tsx` I use it like:

`const { title } = useSiteMetaData();`

Below my header component:

```
const Header: FC<Props> = () => {
  const styles = Styles();
  const { title } = useSiteMetaData();

  return (
    <header css={styles.root}>
      <Logo siteTitle={title} />
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

To generate types for my graphql queries, I am using Gatsby plugin [Gatsby Typescript Graphql Codegen](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-graphql-codegen/).

It generates a file `graphql-types.ts`. From this file I can import my graphql queries:

```
import { SiteMetaDataQuery } from '../../graphql-types'
```

In my custom hook, I try to use it like:

```
const useSiteMetadata = () => {
  const { site }: SiteMetaDataQuery = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query SiteMetaData {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            author
            year
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  );
  return site?.siteMetadata;
};
```

But then inside `Header.tsx` (where I use the hook), I get the following error:

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Maybe<Pick<SiteSiteMetadata,
> "title" | "description" | "author" | "year">> | undefined'